# Code in Advanced C++ Metaprogramming does not compile

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am reading the book **[Advanced C++ Metaprogramming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1460966163)** and I encounter that a snippet of code at section 2.2.3. (page 49th) doesn't compile (My current compiler is Visual Studio 2013). The error arises at assignment but the book says that the assignment **"ok: it ends up calling basic_inner::operator=**". Did I miss something?

```
template <typename X, typename T>
struct basic_inner
{
    template <typename T2>
    basic_inner& operator=(const basic_inner<X, T2>&)
    {
        // do something...
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct outer
{
    template <typename X>
    struct inner : public basic_inner<X, T>
    {
        inner& operator=(const basic_inner<X, T> &that)
        {
            static_cast<basic_inner<X, T>&>(*this) = that;
            return *this;
        }
    };
};

template <>
struct outer<int>
{
    template <typename X>
    struct inner : public basic_inner<X, int>
    {
        inner& operator=(const basic_inner<X, int> &that)
        {
            static_cast<basic_inner<X, int>&>(*this) = that;
            return *this;
        }
    };
};
```

The client code is:

```
outer<double>::inner<void> x1;
outer<int>::inner<void> x2;

x1 = x2;    // <-- error: no operator found which takes right-hand operand of type 'outer<int>::inner<void>'(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Most textbooks have dodgy code - check the authors website, they usually sheepishly admit this from time to time. Even better, fix it and email them - they *really* don't like that.

Comment: Does the book present a motivation for this weird code?

Comment: @jrok Sorry I can't realize its presentation. I guess that the inner classes of different specialization have the same detail so that they could been assigned each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **guess** that assignment operator of `basic_inner` class is not visible in your derived class `inner`, due to name hiding. You can put `using basic_inner<X, T>::operator=;` to your `outer` class and get something like this.

```
template <typename T>
struct outer {
  template <typename X>
  struct inner : public basic_inner<X, T> {
    using basic_inner<X, T>::operator=;
    inner& operator=(const basic_inner<X, T>& that) {
      static_cast<basic_inner<X, T>&>(*this) = that;
      return *this;
    }
  };
};

template <>
struct outer<int> {
  template <typename X>
  struct inner : public basic_inner<X, int> {
    using basic_inner<X, int>::operator=;
    inner& operator=(const basic_inner<X, int>& that) {
      static_cast<basic_inner<X, int>&>(*this) = that;
      return *this;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: +1, but... I'd **guess** that this isn't what the author of the code intended. With `using` declaration, neither the `inner::operator=` nor the one in the explicit specialization get called. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d487e97f5e4997f1) (note the `cout` statements and the output). This code got me completely perplexed, wtf.